# React native webview caching / cookie issues after logout page

Tags: react-native, caching, webview, authorization

I have a react native application that uses webviews for authentication. It is used for login / logout. When a user presses the login button, a webview is opened with a login screen. Whenever the user authenticates this screen is closed. Works perfectly fine. Whenever the user presses login again. The webview will re-open and remembers the last login and automatically closes again without the need to enter new login information. This works as intended **(Also remembers users when app is restarted**).

When the user navigates to the logout webview we navigate to the '/logout' webpage and logout is performed. Next time the user uses the 'login' webview, the user needs to re-authenticate. The app will also remember the user this time **but whenever the app is closed the login will not be remembered anymore.** So login is only remembered for the first time, **as soon as the logout webview is used once the user will never be remembered again.** What am I doing wrong? Below you can find some example code:

**Login screen with login / logout button that navigates to the webviews:**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert, Platform, Linking } from "react-native";
import { LoginProps } from "../config/types";
import CustomButton from "../components/CustomButton";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { CONTENT_SPACING } from "../config/Constants";
import { Auth } from "../utils/Auth";

export function LoginScreen({ navigation }: LoginProps) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  async function onLoginButtonPressed() {
    navigation.navigate("LoginWebView");
  }

  async function onLogoutButtonPressed() {
    navigation.navigate("LogoutWebView");
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>{t("loginScreenWelcome")}</Text>
        <CustomButton
          buttonText={t("loginScreenLoginButton")}
          onPress={onLoginButtonPressed}
        />
        <CustomButton
          buttonText={t("loginScreenLogoutButton")}
          onPress={onLogoutButtonPressed}
          disabled={false}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcomeText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: CONTENT_SPACING,
  },
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: "90%",
    margin: 100,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

**The login webview:**

```
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { LoginWebViewProps } from "../config/types";
import { Auth } from "../utils/Auth";

export function LoginWebViewScreen({ navigation }: LoginWebViewProps) {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: "https://example.com/oauth2/api/v1/authorize?client_id=xxx" }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}

        }
      }}
    />
  );
```

**The logout webview:**

```
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { LoginWebViewProps, LogoutWebViewProps } from "../config/types";
import { Auth } from "../utils/Auth";

export function LogoutWebViewScreen({ navigation }: LogoutWebViewProps) {
  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: "https://example/logout.do" }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      onNavigationStateChange={async (navState: { url: string }) => {
        if (navState.url.includes("/login")) {
          navigation.goBack();
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default LogoutWebViewScreen;
```